# Enable .NET Framework 4.0 on Windows Server 2008 R2 as feature

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, .net-framework

How do I enable .NET Framework 4.0 on Windows Server 2008 R2 as a feature? i've already installed the full profile installer but whenever I wish to add 4.0 as a feature to a specific role, it does not show up. What I see is still .Net Framework 3.5.1. I am using Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 Standard edition. Is there anything I should do for .NET Framework 4.0 to show up on features?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think .Net 4.0 is an available feature on Windows Server 2008R2 (which is analogous to Windows 7).

This edition of Windows only shipped with .Net 3.5.1 (Assuming you have Service Pack 1 installed). You need Windows 8 / Windows Server 2012 if you want it to show up as a "feature" or core part of the OS (both of which come with .Net 4.5).

That said, if you've installed the .Net 4.0 full profile on your server via the standalone or web installer that Microsoft provides, that should be sufficient to enable .Net 4.0 for any application that might need it on your server.

Is there a particular reason you need it to show up in the "Features" so that you can enable it for a particular "Role"? None of the Built-In roles should depend upon it.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a two year old question, but for anyone who runs into it. I just ran into this today too. 4.0 Just does not show up in Server Manager because it's not a native feature to 2k8r2

HKLM>Software>Microsoft>Net Framework Setup>DNP>

There will be sub keys for each version you have installed if you want to verify what you have.

Comment: You just repeated what the other two questions already stated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You'll need to actually install either the .NET 4.0 or 4.5 Frameworks themselves (as they aren't "Windows Features" as 3.5 was on your Operating System).
you can only see .NET 3.5 related features in Server Manager. Please refer the below link for more information.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history

Hope this helps.

Comment: I actually installed .NET 4.0 already. but if i want to use it as a feature, i wasnt able to since .NET 3.5.1 is still the one showing.

Comment: I have the same issue... .net 4 is already installed on server 2008 R2, as it tells you when you try to install it. Why is it not listed as a feature?